# p2pool inbound connections

Tags: network, p2pool, nodes, peers, connection

I am trying to get inbound connections on my p2pool instance. I currently have 6 outbound connections and the pool is working fine, but I would like to have more connections (might help get a few less shares, and if nothing else help the network a little bit).

I have been looking around how to do this, it seems like you need to set up a port forward to port 9332 (or 9338 for litecoin). I have never done this before, and have a few miners which are doing OK on my existing pool so before I go ahead and ruin my p2pool node I thought I'd reach out and see if anyone had any experience they would like to share :)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit), thanks for your help!

Comment: You had created three new tags for this question. Please rather check for existing tags before creating new ones. Only create new tags if you are the first to breach a new topic that you feel will gather more questions. Tags are used by other users to follow specific topics and new tags won't be followed by anyone yet, thus are of little use at first for you. At this point it is probably rather rare that one is indeed the first to ask about something. ;) I have replaced the new tags with some existing tags which seemed appropriate. Feel free to edit if you find some better ones.

Comment: Whoops! I'll take those out :) Sorry

Comment: Um. I had already replaced your new tags "inbound, port-forwarding, and iptables" with the existing tags "network, nodes, peers, connection". It seems to me that you missed that bit and deleted what you thought was still your new tags. I rolled back to include those existing tags again, in the hope that I interpret the situation right. ;)

Answer (score 1):

From what we have noticed on LBTC Grid, out refers to connecting to coin network and the P2Pool network. In refers to miners connecting to your server.